# ListCollectionView slow filtering

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Listbox that is binded to an observable collection that I want to filter / sort with the help of an ListCollectionView.

```
<ListBox x:Name="UserContainer" ItemsSource="{Binding allUserViewModel.Users}" 
                             Margin="0,0,0,7"
                             Visibility="{Binding allUserViewModel.HasVisibleUsers, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisCollapsed}}"
                             Background="Transparent" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                             BorderThickness="0" Padding="0"
                             VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"  VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
                             ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemStyle}">

                    <ListBox.Resources>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
                    </ListBox.Resources>

                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <VirtualizingStackPanel />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <local:UserControlButton x:Name="UserControlButton" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

When I try to filter or sort the list, it is very slow. 
I've tried to replace the UserControlButton with a simple Usercontrol with almost no logic and it went a lot faster.

So the problem is that it takes too long to recreate my UserControls.

I've tried to set the IsVirtualizing property to true and set my template to an VirtualizingStackpanel, but that doesn't really help.

Any idea how to fix this ?

EDIT

Some code of the UserControlButton

[UserControlButton.xaml](http://pastebin.com/hh430G6f)

[UserControlButton.cs](http://pastebin.com/BRvz7ffi)

[ViewModel](http://pastebin.com/ZgABL2Ue)

Comment: You have to ask yourself why "It takes too long to recreate my UserControls", what the control is doing ?

Comment: Can you also provide the usercontrolbutton xaml. Also please provide any c# code? Especially the view models?

Comment: Problem is in your 'UserControlButton` code then and not in `ListCollectionView` since replacing it with simple UserControl works good.

Comment: @Dom Added some code of the UserControlButton in my edit.